# Some sort of matrix.

Tags: matrices, reference-request

How do you call this sort of algebraic entity as:
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}
I mean it's not a matrix as in a $m\times n$ array, because we have only 2 complete columns and not $3$ and two rows.

I don't believe you encounter this mathematical object in linear algebra, but I may be mistaken?

Thanks in advance.
Please also provide a reference where this object is defined if there is any?

Comment: You definitely do not encounter this in linear algebra.

Comment: I haven't seen it in a linear algebra setting.  You do see this kind of thing in computer science/data structures.

Comment: @Paul so how is it called in computer science? just plain array?

Comment: This is close to the notion of a filled Young tableau: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau

Comment: I agree with @Travis a boolean version is Ferrers diagram http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FerrersDiagram.html You shouldn't use the matrix formalism for it : if there is a connection with linear algebra, it is not there